# How can I maintain/edit realm database with local JSON files without overwriting existing data?

Tags: json, swift, realm

I have a question/answer app with local JSON.  I want to update JSON with new questions for the table view and delete the duplicate questions that emerge in the realm database with each app reload and keep the new questions.

Based on a previously answered question, I implemented the strategy below, which provides the tableview with single question objects. I use a uuid as the primary key and each question also has an individual questionid. With each reload, a new uuid is made for each question causing duplicates in the realm database. I would like to keep only new question items upon reloading app while deleting the duplicates.  I have an example of my database below too showing what is happening.

JSON Maintenance Functions within App Delegate:

```
        //MARK: - Read Local JSON File
        
        func readLocalJSONFile(forName name: String) -> Data? {
            do {
                if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: "json") {
                    let fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
                    let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileUrl)
                    
                    return data
                }
            } catch {
                print("error: \(error)")
            }
            return nil
        }
                
        //MARK: - Parse JSON
        
        func parseJSON(jsonData: Data){
            
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let result = try decoder.decode([Question].self, from: jsonData)
                if realm.object(ofType: Question.self, forPrimaryKey: "_id" ) != nil{
                   
                } else{
                try realm.write{


                    for question in result{
                    
                     let questionClass = Question()
                     questionClass._id = question._id
                     questionClass.questionid = question.questionid
                     questionClass.date = question.date
                     questionClass.text = question.text
                     questionClass.answer1 = question.answer1
                     questionClass.answer2 = question.answer2
                     questionClass.answer3 = question.answer3
                     questionClass.answer4 = question.answer4
                     questionClass.score = question.score
                     questionClass.color = question.color
                     self.realm.add(questionClass, update: .modified)
                    

                    
                        }
                    }
                }
                
    
            }catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            
            }
        
        
        //MARK: - Data Manipulation Methods

        func loadProfiles(){

            if let localData = readLocalJSONFile(forName: K.minketClues) {
                    parseJSON(jsonData: localData)
            
                }
    
        func deleteAllRealm() {
            try! realm.write {
                realm.deleteAll()
        }
        }
                
      }
        
        loadProfiles()
```

Question Model

```
class Question: Object, Decodable{
    
    @objc dynamic var _id: String = UUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var questionid: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var date: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var text: String  = ""
    @objc dynamic var answer1: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var answer2: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var answer3: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var answer4: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var score: Bool = false
    @objc dynamic var color: String = "#30336b"
    let answers = List<Answers>()
   
    
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case _id,questionid,date,text,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4}
    
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws{
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        
      //  _id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: ._id)
        questionid = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .questionid)
        date = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .date)
        text = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .text)
        answer1 = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .answer1)
        answer2 = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .answer2)
        answer3 = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .answer3)
        answer4 = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .answer4)
        super.init()
    }
    
    override static func primaryKey() -> String?
    {
        return "_id"
    }
    
    required override init()
    {
        super.init()
    }

    required init(value: Any, schema: RLMSchema)
    {
        super.init()
    }

    required init(realm: RLMRealm, schema: RLMObjectSchema)
    {
        super.init()
    }
    

    

    
}
```

UPDATE/POTENTIAL SOLUTION:

```
         func parseJSON(jsonData: Data){
            
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let result = try decoder.decode([Question].self, from: jsonData)
                
                    for question in result{
                         
                         let questionClass = Question()
                         questionClass._id = question._id
                         questionClass.questionid = question.questionid
                         questionClass.date = question.date
                         questionClass.text = question.text
                         questionClass.answer1 = question.answer1
                         questionClass.answer2 = question.answer2
                         questionClass.answer3 = question.answer3
                         questionClass.answer4 = question.answer4
                         questionClass.score = question.score
                         questionClass.color = question.color

                    
                        if let currentObject = realm.object(ofType:Question.self, forPrimaryKey: question.questionid){
                            questionClass.score = currentObject.score
                            questionClass.color = currentObject.color
                        }
                        try! realm.write{
                            realm.add(questionClass, update: .modified)
                        }

                        

                        }
                    
                    
             
         
            }catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            
            }
```

Comment: The description of the problem is a bit confusing; *I want to update JSON with new questions for the table view without overwriting the realm database* JSON has nothing to do with the Realm database. e.g. you can write JSON to you local disk all day and that has no correlation to a Realm Database. Of course that leads to the question of why are you using JSON when you've got Realm? Just store all of your data in Realm to start with? Can you clarify the question and what the trouble is?

Comment: The problem I've been working on is finding a way to save Question Model items (currently represented in JSON format) into realm database and add new question items without overwriting the realm database and undoing changes noted by answering correct answers. Right now, I used JSON/decodable to parse question model data and write into realm database. I thought that using JSON/decodable was the way to save items in realm database. Is there a way to write the Question Model items directly into realm database without parsing JSON and writing to realm? Are you referring to doing that via MongoDB?

Comment: I am not sure why or how you're *overwriting the realm database* - adding an object will never overwrite the entire database, just that object and only if it's exists (according to the primary key). Saving an object to the realm database is as shown in your question `realm.add(result, update: .modified)` so I am not sure what the issue is there. As far as duplicates; you will need some strategy to identify what a duplicate is; do the questions have a unique ID or some other unique identifying information? The question really needs clarity and context. Please update it so we can try to help.

Comment: @Jay, I edited the question based on additional work I did and thinking more about what I wanted to ask. I am trying to figure out how to delete duplicate question models from my realm database when I reload app.

Comment: I am looking at your code and see you're reading in a .json file, parsing it and writing out Realm objects, `QuestionClass`. There's nothing in the code that checks or tries to prevent duplicate data so... you'll end up with duplicate data if the file is read over and over. A simple solution would be to read in the json, instantiate the Question Object and then perform a Realm filter for any objects with the same id. If the results.count > 0 then it already exists. Toss it out and try the next one. Rinse and repeat. That would prevent duplicate questions from being created.

Comment: Thank you, @Jay. I was able to get rid of duplicates with your suggestion and the solution above. The ongoing issue is updating the realm database with new questions when I add them to the local JSON. With the current code, when I add new items in the JSON, they do not get made into Question Objects in Realm Database unless I delete the app and re-download it. Is there a way to dynamically create new Question Models when new items are added to JSON?

Comment: That comment is quite unclear as Realm has nothing to do with JSON. Adding questions to a local JSON file will not invoke any Realm code so it's not clear what you're expecting.